# Текстура не полностью натягивается на кнопку

Tags: java, android, libgdx

У меня есть кнопка ImageButton, размер которой больше размера текстуры.

```
ImageButton button = new ImageButton(buttonsSkin.getDrawable("b0"), buttonsSkin.getDrawable("b1"));
button.setSize(1000, 500);
stage.addActor(button);
```

При этом текстура не растягивается на всю кнопку, а располагается в её центре. Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить.

Comment: Необходимо добавить в вопрос [минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle

```
TextureAtlas mainMenuAtlas = Assets.manager.get("mainmenu/mainMenu.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);//если есть менеджер ассетов - загрузите ваш атлас с изображениями
Skin buttonsSkin = new Skin(mainMenuAtlas);

ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle connectToHost = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
connectToHost.up = buttonsSkin.getDrawable("menu-connect-btn");//кнопка не нажата
connectToHost.over = buttonsSkin.getDrawable("menu-connect-btn");
connectToHost.down = buttonsSkin.getDrawable("menu-connect-btn-down"); // кнопка нажата

ImageButton gameClientButton = new ImageButton(connectToHost);
gameClientButton.setSize(100, 200);// размер кнопки
gameClientButton.setPosition(10, 10); // позиция кнопки(с нижнего левого угла координаты считаются)
gameClientButton.addListener(new ClientListener()); //действие при нажатии
stage.addActor(gameClientButton ); //добавляем кнопку к сцене
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно растянуть на всю кнопку, вам абсолютно ненужен `ImageButton`. Используйте обычный `Button`, и задавайте ему `background`

Comment: Но мне нужны разные картинка для нажатой и ненажатой

Comment: @qw123, ну так выставьте StateListDrawable в background